# CSS Right Sidebar Alignment

Tags: css, alignment, html, sidebar, right-align

I just had a website turned over to me and all was fine. I haven't touched any of the files, but the other day I went online and the right sidebar (videos and sponsors) is now showing underneath the main content. (There are maybe two other people with access to the FTP on their end... not sure why they'd change code.)

In my editor, it is showing it correctly, but obviously not the case online now. I'm assuming either something isn't closed properly or maybe something to do with padding possibly? I feel rather silly that I can't seem to figure out what is probably an obvious issue and could use a second pair of eyes to guide me in the right direction.

Here's the index.php:

```
  <?php 
include('assets/config.php');
include('assets/functions.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Big Time Sports Ohio" />
<meta name="author" content="Timothy Patterson - redneckg33k@gmail.com(phpg33k.com)" />
<meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW" />

<title>Big Time Sports Ohio&nbsp;|&nbsp;Home Page</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css" /> <!-- Foundation style sheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css-teams/oaklandraiders.css" /> <!-- Relace with your teams style sheet -->

<!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css" /><![endif]-->

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png" />
<link rel='index' title='Big Time Sports Ohio' href='index.php' />

</head>
<body>

<div id="header">
<div class="center relative">

<!-- Logo -->
<a href="index.html" title="Big Time Sports Ohio" class="logo" ><img src="images/logo.png" height="108" width="272" alt="Big Time Sports Ohio" /></a>

<div id="navigation">
    <div class="menu-header-menu-container">
        <?php include('assets/nav.php'); ?>
    </div><!-- end .menu-header-menu-container -->
</div><!-- end #navigation -->
</div><!-- end .center .relative -->

</div><!-- end #header -->


<div id="content-container" class="slider-nav">
  <div class="center calltoaction"> 

<div class="callaction-bg">
    <div class="textcenter">
    <div class="callaction-text">
        Welcome to the all new<br />
        <strong>Big Time Sports Ohio</strong>
    </div><!-- end .callaction-text -->


    </div> <!-- end .textcenter -->
    <div style="float:left;margin-top:10px;"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/BigTimeSportsOhio"><img src="images/BookmarkIconsFacebook.png" style="padding:5px;margin-top:25px;"></a>&nbsp;<a href="https://twitter.com/btsohio"><img src="images/BookmarkIconsTwitter.png" style="padding:5px;"></a></div>   
</div> <!-- .callaction-bg -->

<div id="carousel-wrap">    
     <?php include('assets/preview.php'); ?>
 </div> <!-- end #carousel-wrap -->

<br class="clear" />

<div id="body-wrap">
<hr />

    <div id="home-content">

        <!-- LATEST BLOG POSTS -->
        <div class="blog-posts">                    
                <?php main() ?>
        </div><!-- end #blog-posts -->

        <br />
        <br />
        <!-- CATEGORY POSTS -->
<!-- end #category-posts -->                    
</div>
  </div> <!-- end #home-content -->

  <div id="sidebar">
      <?php include('assets/sidebar.php');?>    
  </div><!-- end #sidebar -->

</div> 
<!-- #body-wrap -->

<br class="clear" />

</div><!-- end .center .calltoaction-->
</div><!-- end #content-container .slider-nav-bg -->

<div id="footer">
<?php include('assets/footer.php');?>
</div><!-- end #footer -->

<!-- Cufon Font Replacement Scripts -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fonts/Kalinga_400.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Cufon.replace ('#tabs ul.tabnav li a')('#sidebar h2')('.footer-block h2')  ('#sidebar h2 ')('#posts .page-title')('#posts #comments h3')('.callaction-text')('#home-content h2') ('.blog-title')('#category-posts h2')('.postauthor h4') ;
</script>

<!-- jQuery Libraries -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/contact.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hoverIntent.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/superfish.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/image_hover.js"></script>    

<!-- Thumbnail Hover Fade Effect -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        event: 'mouseover'
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#featuredvid").tabs({
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var $featured_content = jQuery('#slider .slide'),
        $tabbed_area = jQuery('#tabbed'),
        $tab_content = jQuery('.tab-content'),
        $controllers = jQuery('div#controllers'),
        $all_tabs = jQuery('#all_tabs');

    if ($tabbed_area.length) {
        $tabbed_area.tabs();
    };
</script>

<!-- Navigation --> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("ul.sf-menu").superfish(); 
}); 

<!-- Slider Settings -->
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        effect:'random',
        slices:'15',
        animSpeed:'1000',
        pauseTime:'8000',
        startSlide:0,
        captionOpacity:0.0
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> Cufon.now(); </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the stylesheet:

```
 /* GLOBAL RESETS BY ERIC MEYER http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ v1.0 | 20080212 */

            html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,font,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td{border:0;outline:0;font-size:100%;vertical-align:baseline;background:transparent;margin:0;padding:0;}
 body{line-height:1;}
 ol,ul{list-style:none;}
 blockquote,q{quotes:none;}
 blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after{content:none;}
 :focus{outline:0;}
 ins{text-decoration:none;}
 del{text-decoration:line-through;}
 table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
 .clearfix:after { visibility: hidden; display: block; font-size: 0; content: " ";           clear: both; height: 0; }
 * html .clearfix             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
 *:first-child+html .clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */

 /* SITE-WIDE STYLE */
 body, select, input, textarea {font: normal 12px "lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;}
 p {line-height:18px;color:#333;padding:5px 0;}
 a {text-decoration:none;}
 a:link {color:#65AAEB;}
 a:visited {color:#65AAEB;}
 a:hover {color:#2f72b1;}
 a:active {color:#2f72b1;}
 blockquote {padding:0 40px;}
 ol {list-style-position:inside;}
 .textwidget {line-height:20px;margin-top:15px;color:#333333;}
 .comments {background:url(images/comment-bubble.png) 0 2px no-repeat;padding-left:15px;}

 /* WP IMAGE ALIGNMENT */
 img.centered {display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}
 img.alignright {padding: 4px;margin: 0 0 2px 7px;display: inline;}
 img.alignleft {padding: 4px;margin: 0 7px 2px 0;display: inline;}
 .alignright {float: right;}
 .alignleft {float: left;}

 /* MISCELLANEOUS CLASSES */
 .right {float: right;}
 .left {float: left;}
 .relative {position: relative;}
 .valign {float: left; vertical-align: middle;}
 hr {width: 100%;height: 1px;border: 0;background: #DDD;margin: 10px 0;}
 p + hr {margin: 12px 0 32px 0;}

 /* BASIC STRUCTURE */
 .center {width: 960px; margin: 0 auto;}
 .clear {clear: both;}
 #content-container {width: 100%;background: #fff;float: left;padding-bottom: 40px; padding-top: 30px;}
 #body-wrap {margin: 0 auto; width: 960px;}

 /* HEADER */
 .logo {display: block;float: left;outline: none;cursor: pointer;margin-top:0px;}
 #header {width: 100%;background: #fff url(images/header-bg.png) bottom left repeat-x;height: 127px;}

 /* NAVIGATION */
 #navigation {width:960px;}
 #navigation ul {float: right; margin: 45px 0px 0px; }
 #navigation ul li {padding-right: 10px; margin-right: 4px; }
 #navigation ul li a {font-size:16px; color: #ffffff; text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px              #031112; display: block; padding:12px 5px 8px 15px; height:22px;}     
 #navigation ul li a:hover, ul.nav {color: #851F2F; text-decoration: none; }
 #navigation li.current_page_item {color:#851F2F;}
 #navigation li.current_page_item a {color:#851F2F;}
 #navigation ul ul {background: url(images/dropdown-bg.png) repeat-y; width: 190px      !important; margin-top:50px; padding: 8px 9px 8px 6px; border: 1px solid #333; }
 #navigationnavigation ul ul li {background: url(images/menu-hr.png) no-repeat bottom left; width: 200px; padding: 0 0 5px 10px; }
 #navigation ul ul li a {background: none; padding: 0px; display: block; text-align: left; padding: 12px 0px 11px 25px;}
 .sf-menu {position: relative; z-index:69;line-height: 1.0;}
 .sf-menu ul {position: absolute;top: -999em;margin: 0;padding: 0;list-style-type: none;width: 200px;}
 .sf-menu li {position: relative;display: inline;float: left;}
 .sf-menu li:hover {visibility: inherit !important;}
 .sf-menu a {display: block;position: relative;text-decoration: none;}
 .sf-menu li:hover ul, .sf-menu li.sfHover ul {left: 0;z-index: 99;top: 5px}
 .sf-menu li:hover li ul, .sf-menu li.sfHover li ul {top: -999em;}
 .sf-menu li li:hover ul, .sf-menu li li.sfHover ul {top: -43px;left: 205px;}
 .sf-menu li li:hover li ul, .sf-menu li li.sfHover li ul {top: -999em;}
 .sf-menu li li li:hover ul, .sf-menu li li li.sfHover ul {top: 0;left: 213px;}
 #navigation .sf-menu li ul li a{width: 200px;padding: 8px 10px 0px 10px      !important;display: block;cursor: pointer; color: #ccc; text-align: left; font-size: 14px;  background: none;}
 #navigation .sf-menu li ul li a:hover {color: #851F2F !important;}
 .sf-menu ul{padding: 25px 10px 15px 15px;font-size: .8em;text-transform: none !important;cursor: pointer;width: 200px;z-index:9999;}

 /* PAGINATION */
 .wp-pagenavi {clear: both;color:#999}
 .wp-pagenavi a, .wp-pagenavi span {color:#999;text-decoration: none;border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;padding: 3px 5px;margin: 2px;}
 .wp-pagenavi a:hover, .wp-pagenavi span.current {border-color: #ccc;}
 .wp-pagenavi span.current {font-weight: bold;color:#666;}

 /* CALL TO ACTION */
 .callaction-bg {width: 100%; background: url(images/action-bg.png) top left repeat-x; height: 138px; margin-top: 10px;}
 .calltoaction {position: relative; width: 100%;}
 .textcenter {margin: 0 auto; width: 960px;}
 #callaction-button {float: right; width: 173px; height: 71px; background:      url(images/button.png) top left no-repeat; background-position:100% 0; margin-top: 36px;}
 #callaction-button:hover,#callaction-button:focus,#callaction-button:active {background-position:0 0;}
 .callaction-text {float: left; width: 540px; padding-top: 20px; font-size: 33px; color: #fff; text-transform: uppercase; line-height: 52px;}
 .callaction-text strong {float: left; font-size: 40px; color: #851f2f; text-transform: uppercase; line-height: 40px;}

 /* IMAGE ROW HOME PAGE */
 #carousel-wrap {width:960px;margin:0 auto;margin-top:20px;padding-bottom:50px;}
 .fadeThis {position:relative;display:block;height: 100px;width: 100px;}
 .hover {position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;display: none;height: 100px;width: 100px;background:url(images/hover.png) 0 0 no-repeat;}
 .carousel-image {float:left;background:url(images/thumbnail-bg.gif) no-repeat;width:115px;height:115px;padding-top:5px;padding-left:5px;}

 /* HOME CONTENT */
 #home-content {width:570px;float:left;margin-top:0px;}
 #home-content h2 {text-transform:uppercase;font-size:18px;color:#333;}
 #home-content h3 {text-transform:uppercase;font-size:20px;color:#333;}
 .blog-posts {margin-bottom:20px;margin-top:-10px;}
 .home-post-title {width:570px;height:38px;text-transform:uppercase;padding-top:30px;}
 .home-post-title a {color:#333;font-size:22px;}
 .home-post-title a:hover {color:#851F2F;}
 .meta {margin:-10px 0 10px 0;}
 .meta p {color:#8b8b8b;}
 .meta a {color:#65aaeb;}
 .meta a:hover {color:#2f72b1;}
 .readmore {background:url(images/read-more.png) no-repeat;width:82px;height:34px;float:right;margin: -10px 0 30px 0;}
 .readmore:hover {background:url(images/read-more-hover.png) no-repeat;}
 .home-thumbnail {display:inline;float:left; margin: 10px 8px 5px 0;}

 /* HOME CATEGORIES */
 #first-category {width:250px;min-height:310px;float:left;}
 #second-category {width:250px;min-height:310px;float:right;}
 #category-posts {margin-top:-20px;min-height:200px;}
 #category-posts h2 {font-size:14px;color:#333333;margin-bottom:-3px;}
 .cat-thumbnail {margin-bottom:10px;border:1px solid #999;border-right:1px solid #fff;border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #ccc;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #ccc;
 }
 .cat-post-title {width:250px;font-size:16px;text-transform:uppercase;}
 .cat-post-title a {text-decoration:none;color:#333;}
 .cat-post-title a:hover {color:#851F2F;}
 .category-meta {margin-top:-2px;}
 .category-meta p {color:#8b8b8b;}
 .category-meta a {color:#65aaeb;}
 .category-meta:hover {color:#2f72b1;}
 #first-cat-list {float:left;width:260px;}
 #second-cat-list {float:right;width:260px;margin-right:-12px;}
 #featured-cat-lists ul {min-height:200px;list-style:none inside url(images/arrow.png);font-size: 12px; padding-top: 8px; line-height: 20px; margin-top: 10px;}
 #featured-cat-lists ul li {padding: 7px 0 7px 0px;border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;}
 #featured-cat-lists ul a {color: #545454;text-decoration: none;}
 #featured-cat-lists ul a:hover {color: #851F2F;text-decoration: none;}

 /* POSTS */
 #posts {width:570px;float:left;margin-top:15px;}
 #posts img {background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #DBDBDB;border-bottom:1px solid      #ABABAB;border-right:1px solid #ABABAB;margin:5px 10px 5px 0;padding:4px;}
 #posts ul {list-style:none;}
 #posts .meta {padding:15px 0 10px 0;}
 #posts .meta p {color:#8b8b8b;}
 #posts .meta a {color:#65aaeb;}
 #posts .meta a:hover {color:#2f72b1;}
 #posts .page-title {font-size:20px;}
 .blog-posts {margin-bottom:20px;}
 .blog-title {width:570px;line-height:20px;color:#fff;font-size:20px;text-transform:uppercase;padding-bottom:5px;}
 .single-title {position:relative;top:5px;width:570px;line-height:20px;color:#fff;font-size:20px;text-transform:uppercase;margin-bottom:5px;}
 .single-title a, .blog-title a {color:#333;}
 .single-title a:hover , .blog-title a:hover {color:#851F2F;}
 .single-sidebar {padding-left:20px;}
 #blog-page-title {border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;font-size: 32px;text-transform:uppercase;margin-bottom:20px;color:#fff;text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #999;}
 .blog-content img {float:left;}
 .blog-post-details {margin:0 0;overflow:hidden;}
 #crumbs {position:relative;top:-10;}

 /* FULL WIDTH */
 #posts-full {width:960px;margin-top:0px;float:left;margin-top:15px;}

 /* AUTHOR BIO BOX */
 .postauthor {background: #EBEBEB; border-top: 1px solid #e1e1e0; border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e0; padding-bottom:10px;margin:20px 0px;overflow: hidden;}
 .postauthor img {float: left; margin: 5px 10px 0 10px!important; }
 .postauthor h4 {color: #666; font-size: 18px; margin: 10px 0 0 0;}
 .postauthor h4 a {margin-left:-5px;}
 .postauthor p {color: #515151; font-size: 13px; margin: -18px 0 0 10px;line-height:20px;}

 /* COMMENT FORM */
 #posts #comments h3{color:#851F2F;font-size:22px;font-weight:400;text-shadow:0 1px 0      #fff;margin:0 0 23px 0;padding-bottom:10px;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;}
 #posts #comments ol.commentlist{list-style:none;margin:0 0 40px;}
 #posts #comments ol.commentlist li{clear:both;border-bottom:1px solid #d1c7b3;margin:0 0 24px;padding:0 0 24px;}
 #posts #comments ol.commentlist ul{margin:0 0 0 20px;}
 #posts #comments ol.commentlist ul li{border:none;margin:0 0 24px 20px;padding:0;}
 #posts #comments .comment{overflow:hidden;}
 #posts #comments .comment .avatar{float:left;border:1px solid #d1c7b3;margin:0 15px 10px 0;}
 #posts #comments .comment .commenttext{width:404px;float:left;}
 #posts #comments .comment p{font-size:14px;line-height:24px;margin:0px 0 5px 0;}
 #posts #comments .comment cite{font:italic 18px Georgia, Serif;margin:0 0 5px;}
 #posts #comments .comment span{display:none;}
 #posts #comments .comment ul.children {margin-top:40px;}
 #posts #comments .comment .comment-meta{float:right;font:italic 11px Georgia, Serif;margin-top:-20px;}
 #posts #comments .comment .reply a{display:block;clear:both;float:right;font:italic 15px Georgia, Serif;}
 #posts #comments .comment .cancel a{display:block;float:right;clear:both;font:italic 15px Georgia, Serif;}
 #posts #comments #respond{clear:both;margin:0 0 50px;}
 #posts #comments #respond form label{float:left;clear:left;width:80px;text-align:right;font-size:17px;margin:7px 10px 0 0;}
 #posts #comments #respond form           input{float:left;width:250px;height:16px;background:#EBEBEB;border:1px solid #ccc;font:15px      Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;color:#666;margin:0 20px 10px 0;padding:10px;}
 #posts #comments #respond form textarea{float:left;width:400px;height:120px;background:#EBEBEB;border:1px solid           #ccc;font:15px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;color:#666;margin:0 0 10px;padding:10px;}
 #posts #comments #respond form input.commentsubmit{width:100px;height:40px;background-     color:#EBEBEB;border:1px solid #ccc;color:#666;text-shadow:0 1px 0      #fff;cursor:pointer;margin:10px 0 0 90px;}
 #posts #comments #respond form input.commentsubmit:hover {color:#851F2F;}
 #posts #comments #respond form input:focus,#posts #comments #respond form      textarea:focus{background:#DCDCDC;}

 /* SIDEBAR */
 #sidebar {width: 350px;float: left;min-height: 650px;height: auto;margin-top:23px;padding-left:30px;}
 #sidebar h2 {color:#333;text-transform:uppercase;background-color:#ebebeb;padding:10px 0 10px 15px;border:1px solid #E4E4E4;font-size:15px;margin-bottom:10px;}
 .sidebar-widget {margin-bottom:50px;}
 #sidebar ul {font-size: 12px; padding-top: 8px; line-height: 20px; margin-top: 10px;}
 #sidebar ul li {padding: 7px 0 7px 16px;border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;}
 #sidebar ul a {color: #545454;text-decoration: none;}
 #sidebar ul a:hover {color: #851F2F;text-decoration: none;}

 /* FOOTER */
 #footer {width: 100%; background-color:#000;padding: 40px 0 10px 0;clear: both;height:100%;}
 #footer-alt {clear: both;width: 100%;height:49px;background: url(images/copyright-bg.png) repeat-x;margin-bottom:-10px;}
 #copyright {width:960px;margin:0 auto;}
 #copyright p {width:500px;float:left;padding-top:20px;color:#333;}
 #footer-nav {float:right;padding-top:5px;margin-right:20px;}
 .footer-block {width:300px;float:left; margin:0 20px 50px 0;}
 .footer-block h2 {background:url(images/widget-title.png) no-repeat;width:310px;height:40px;font-size:16px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#ccc;padding:10px 0 0 20px;}
 #footer p {color:#727272;}
 #footer a {color: #727272;text-decoration: none;}
 #footer a:hover {color: #851F2F;text-decoration: none;}
 #footer ul {font-size: 12px; padding-top: 8px; line-height: 20px;}
 #footer ul li {padding: 7px 0 7px 16px;border-bottom: 1px solid #181818;}
 #footer ul a {color: #727272;text-decoration: none;}
 #footer ul a:hover {color: #851F2F;text-decoration: none;}
 #footer .textwidget {color: #727272;}
 .about-fan {margin-top:15px;}
 .about-fan img {padding:7px 10px 1px 0;float:left;}
 .about-fan span {color:#727272;line-height:18px;}

 /* HOME SLIDER */
 #slider-wrap {width: 100%;float: left;background: url(images/slider-bg.png) top left      repeat-x #033369;height: 397px;margin-top:-3px;}
 #slider-wrap .center {height: 396px;position: relative;}
 .slider-shadow {background:url(images/slider-shadow.png) no-repeat;width:922px;height:155px;position:relative;top:275px;margin:0 auto;z-index:20}
 .nivoSlider {position:relative;z-index:40;}
 .nivoSlider img {position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;}
 .nivoSlider a.nivo-imageLink      {position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;border:0;padding:0;margin:0;z-     index:60;display:none;}
 .nivo-slice {display:block;position:absolute;z-index:40;height:100%;}
 .nivo-caption      {position:absolute;left:0px;bottom:0px;height:50px;background:#000;color:#fff;opacity:0.8; /          /* Overridden by captionOpacity setting */width:100%;z-index:79;}
 .nivo-caption p {padding:5px;margin:12px 0 0 10px;font-size:20px;color:#fff;font-     family:century gothic;font-weight:100;text-transform:uppercase;}
 .nivo-directionNav a {position:absolute;top:45%;z-index:89;cursor:pointer;}
 .nivo-prevNav {left:0px;}
 .nivo-nextNav {right:0px;}
 .nivo-controlNav a {position:relative;z-index:89;cursor:pointer;}
 .nivo-controlNav a.active {font-weight:bold;}
 #slider {width:960px;margin:0 auto;    background:#202834 url(images/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;margin-top:30px;}
 #slider a{display:block;}
 #slider img {position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;display:none;}
 .slider-nav {background: #fff url(images/slider-nav.jpg) left top repeat-x      !important;padding-top: 40px;}
 .nivo-controlNav {position:absolute;left:47%;bottom:-64px;}
 .nivo-controlNav a      {display:block;width:20px;height:20px;background:url(images/bullets.png) no-repeat;text-     indent:-9999px;border:0;margin-right:3px;float:left;}
 .nivo-controlNav a.active {background-position:-20px 0;}
 .nivo-directionNav a {width:32px;height:34px;background:url(images/arrows.png) no-     repeat;text-indent:-9999px;border:0;}
 a.nivo-nextNav {background-position:-32px 0;right:10px;}
 a.nivo-prevNav {left:10px;}

 /* CONTACT FORM */
 {.buttoncontact {background-image:url(images/send-now.gif);background-repeat:no-repeat;border:0;width:97px;height:33px;cursor:pointer;float:left;margin:10px 10px 0 323px;padding:0;}}
 form{margin:0;padding:0;}
 #contact-area{width:406px;margin:49px 0 0 86px;}
 .map{background-color:#ebebeb;float:left;margin:0;padding:12px;}
 .contact-separator{width:52px;height:398px;margin-top:49px;background-     image:url(images/dot-separator.png);background-position:right;background-repeat:repeat-y;float:left;}
 #contact-wrap{width:500px;float:left;}
 #contact-form {margin:20px 0;}
 #contact-form label{font-size:1.1em;width:100px;float:left;font-weight:400;clear:both;margin-bottom:3px;}
 .textfield,input#s{float:left;font-family:Tahoma, Arial, verdana;font-size:12px;margin-bottom:13px;color:#8a8a8a;width:406px;height:22px;background-color:#fff;border:2px solid #ebebeb;padding:3px;}
 .textarea{border:2px solid #ebebeb;float:left;font-family:Tahoma, Arial, verdana;font-size:12px;color:#8a8a8a;width:406px;height:116px;background-color:#fff;overflow:hidden;margin:0;padding:3px;}
 .buttoncontact{background-image:url(images/send-now.gif);background-repeat:no-repeat;border:0;width:97px;height:33px;cursor:pointer;float:right;margin:20px -10px 0 0;padding:0;}
 #emailSuccess{width:355px;border-top:1px solid #91E691;border-bottom:1px solid      #91E691;background-color:#E0FFE0;color:#007500;text-align:center;display:none;padding:7px 30px;}
 .require{display:none;}
 .loading{margin-top:15px;float:left;background:url(images/loading-contact.gif) top left no-repeat;padding-left:32px;font-size:1.1em;color:#a5a6a6;margin-left:10px;}
 label.screen-reader-text{margin:0 10px;}
 input#searchsubmit{padding:5px;}

 /* 404 ERROR PAGE */
 #sitemap {margin-top:55px;}
 #sitemap ul {list-style:none inside url(images/list-arrow.png);font-size: 14px; padding-top: 8px; line-height: 20px;}
 #sitemap ul li {padding: 7px 0 7px 16px;}
 #sitemap ul a {color: #333;text-decoration: none;}
 #sitemap ul a:hover {color: #851F2F;text-decoration: none;}

 /* WIDGET TABS */
 #sidebar div#tabs {width:350px;margin-bottom:30px;}
 #tabs ul {padding-top:0;}
 #tabs ul li {padding:10px 0 10px 17px;border-bottom:none;border-top:1px solid #ccc;}
 #tabs ul li:hover {background-color:#EBEBEB;}
 #tabs ul li h4 a {font-size:14px;color:#666;position:relative;top:5px;}
 #tabs ul li p, #tabs ul li a  {font-size:12px;color:#999;}
 #tabs ul li .tabmeta {}
 #tabs ul.tabnav {background:url(images/tabs/tabbed-right-bg.png) repeat-y top      right;border-top:1px solid #fff;}
 #tabs ul.tabnav li{text-align:center;float:left;padding:2px 0 0;list-style:none;}
 #tabs .tabbed ul li{background:none;}
 #tabs ul.tabnav li a{font-size:18px;color:#851F2F !important;text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #ccc;float:left;text-decoration:none;padding-left:2px;text-transform:uppercase;}
 #tabs ul.tabnav li a span{display:block;padding:11px 0 11px;}
 #tabs ul.tabnav li.first a span{width:110px;}
 #tabs ul.tabnav li.second a span{width:120px;}
 #tabs ul.tabnav li.last a span{width:113px;}
 .tabnav li a:hover,.tabnav li a:active,.tabnav li.ui-tabs-selected a{text-decoration:none;background-color:#ececec;}
 #tabs ul.tabnav li.ui-state-active{border-right:1px solid #d1d1d1;padding-top:3px;margin-top:0px;}
 #tabs ul.tabnav li.ui-state-active a{background:url(images/tabs/tabs-left-bg.png) repeat-y scroll 0 0 transparent;background-color:#f0f0f0;}
 #tabs .tabdiv {border-right:1px solid #d1d1d1;border-bottom:1px solid      #d1d1d1;background:#f0f0f0 url(images/tabs/tabs-left-bg.png) repeat-y;}
 #tabs .tabdiv ul{list-style:none;margin-top:44px;}
 #all_tabs{margin-top:-2px;}
 #tabs .tabdiv ul img{border-right:1px solid #fff;border-bottom:1px solid #fff;}
 .tab-thumbnail {display:inline;float:left; margin: 10px 8px 0 0;border:1px solid #999;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #ccc;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #ccc;
 }
 #tabs span.title{color:#313131;font-size:14px;display:block;margin-top:10px;}
 .ui-tabs-hide{display:none;}
 ul.pagination{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
height:100%;
overflow:hidden;
font:12px 'Tahoma';
list-style-type:none;   
 }

 ul.pagination li.details{
     padding:7px 10px 7px 10px;
     font-size:14px;
 }

 ul.pagination li.dot{padding: 3px 0;}

 ul.pagination li{
float:left;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
margin-left:5px;
 }

 ul.pagination li:first-child{
margin-left:0px;
 }

 ul.pagination li a{
color:black;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
padding:7px 10px 7px 10px;
 }

 ul.pagination li a img{
border:none;
 }
 ul.pagination li.details{
   color:#202020;
}
ul.pagination li a {
    border:solid 1px;
    border-radius:3px;  
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    padding:6px 9px 6px 9px;
}

ul.pagination li{
    padding-bottom:1px;
}

ul.pagination li a:hover,
ul.pagination li a.current {    
    color:#FFFFFF;
    box-shadow:0px 1px #EDEDED;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 1px #EDEDED;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 1px #EDEDED;
    text-shadow:0px 1px #3C3C3C;
    border-color:#202020;
    background:#525252;
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#9F9F9F 1px,#6C6C6C 1px,#525252);
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,color-stop(0.02,#9F9F9F),color-stop(0.02,#6C6C6C),color-stop(1,#525252));        
}
ul.pagination li a  {
    color:#444444;
    border-color:#BEBEBE;
    background:#FAFAFA;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your live site and i see a few things that need to be updated.

home-content needs a bigger width i tried 960 to match the rest of the page. Then you need to add a width to .blog-posts perhaps around 500px and then add a float left to it and it should work i just did this all through inspect elements and made it work

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Travis. That did the trick. I did something similar and just forgot to add the float. *facepalm*

I appreciate you taking the time to take a look. Much better now!

Comment: Not a problem at all! Cheers have a great weekend!